# Under what circumstance will JVM stop printing gc.log?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

My application's gc.log reveals the following information:

```
2015-05-23T03:51:10.086+0800: 648560.384: [GC 648560.384: [ParNew: 311342K->3965K(409600K), 0.0025980 secs] 390090K->82715K(1433600K), 0.0028290 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2015-05-23T03:51:10.506+0800: 648560.804: [GC 648560.804: [ParNew: 311165K->3784K(409600K), 0.0030820 secs] 389915K->82536K(1433600K), 0.0032760 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2015-05-25T15:20:54.421+0800: 862744.719: [GC 862744.719: [ParNew: 310984K->3625K(409600K), 0.0032810 secs] 389736K->82379K(1433600K), 0.0036910 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2015-05-25T15:20:54.549+0800: 862744.846: [GC 862744.846: [ParNew: 310825K->11547K(409600K), 0.0037930 secs] 389579K->90305K(1433600K), 0.0040420 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

As you can see, the gc.log stopped printing from 2015-05-23:03:51:10 to 2015-05-25:15:20:54.

My application is a long running server side application, and it is based on Netty. So basically it is **not** possible that there is no garbages to collect in these hours.

And it is not because the disk is full. There is plenty of space left.

This is my JVM arguments:

```
-Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -verbose:gc -Xloggc:./gc.log -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10 -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:SurvivorRatio=3  -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps  -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

Comment: "So basically it is not possible that there is no garbages to collect in these hours." that is entirely possible if the server is sitting idle and thus not producing any garbage

Comment: @the8472 thx for the reply, but I'm pretty sure there are garbage even if the server is idle, because there are always background threads that could generate new objects. That part is my monitor codes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long long google, I found the problem.

It's actually a bug in linux. Please refer to [this google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64)

This is really a big "ouch".